# FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-18 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: in android volley with lower version devices

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-volley

I am getting frequently OOM with volley library in lower versions of android devices.

I am using BitmapLruCache

```
public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {

public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    return cacheSize;
}

public BitmapLruCache() {
    this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
}

public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
    super(sizeInKiloBytes);
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    put(url, bitmap);
}
```

}

Your suggestions will be appreciated. Thank You.

```
03-11 12:24:02.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18454): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-18
03-11 12:24:02.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18454): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=19463KB, Allocated=14480KB, Bitmap Size=10107KB)
03-11 12:24:02.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.ByteArrayPool.getBuf(ByteArrayPool.java:101)
03-11 12:24:02.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.PoolingByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(PoolingByteArrayOutputStream.java:53)
03-11 12:24:02.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.entityToBytes(BasicNetwork.java:203)
03-11 12:24:02.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:104)
03-11 12:24:02.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
```

Comment: Are you using BitmapLruCache for bitmaps ?

Comment: yes, I am using public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was getting Out Of Memory exception when I was trying to download 10 images with size 2 MB.

As volley itself says that It can not download or upload large amount of data.

Here, I fixed OOM by re-sizing images to lower size as possible as i want in server.

**Example:** Actually I need images with sizes 400x200 but It was with sizes 1500x1600 in server, so I made images with sizes 400x200 in server and my list view is easily downloading images from server.

Comment: This fix is great if you have full control over the images being placed on the server. Its not much of a fix for when users upload a vast array of images in different sizes. Great idea though

Answer (score 3):

**For low memory devices** -

LRU Bitmap cache takes too much memory for low-memory devices.

Check Explanation - [bug 50733: Fix OOM error on low-memory devices](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/wiki/mediawiki-cvs/381123).